# Are the sets in 1-4 vector spaces on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are the sets in 1-4 vector spaces on $\mathbb{R}$?

1. $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x+y+z=0\}$
2. $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x+y=0$ and $x+z=0\}$
3. The space of polynomials $p(x)$ of degree m with real coefficients such that $p(0)=0$.
4. The spaces of polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $\leq m$ with **complex** coefficients such that $p(0)=0$.

Note: Elements of $\mathbb{F}$ are callaed scalars.

By definition, a vector space $\nu$ is a nonempty set with two operations: addition "+" and multiplication "$\cdot$" by scalars such that the following conditions are satisfied for any $x,y,z \in \nu$ and any $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$.

- $x+y=y+x$
- $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$
- $x+z=y$ has a unique solution z for each pair $(x,y)$
- $\alpha(\beta x)=(\alpha \beta)x$
- $(\alpha + \beta) x=\alpha x + \beta x$
- $\alpha (x+y)=\alpha x + \alpha x$
- $1x=x$

How can I apply this definition to the problem? I do not seek the answer for all four parts. If someone can help me do number 1 and number 4.

Comment: What is stopping you from just verifying those conditions for (1) and (4)?

Comment: For a subset of a vector space (using the given operations), you just need to check 1) closure under addition and 2) closure under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), $(x,y,z) = (x,y,-x-y) = x(1,0,-1) + y(0,1,-1)$, and this shows that the set is spanned by two linearly independent vectors $(1,0,-1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$. This set is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For 4), it is a vector subspace since $(p+q)(0) = p(0) + q(0) = 0 + 0 = 0$, and $(rp)(0) = rp(0) = r\cdot 0 = 0$, for any $r \in R$, and $p, q \in P$.

Comment: So I don't need to verify the properties above? Only multiplication and addition?

Comment: Yes you are right.